# Loading from SYS in SmileBASIC

Tags: discussion

(SmileBASIC is a BASIC interpreter for the Nintendo 3DS)

SmileBASIC has a special "folder" named `SYS` that contains built in resources, such as the default sprite sheets, font, and sample programs.
It cannot be modified, since it's not actually a folder; it's stored in the game's ROM. (It's just treated as a folder so you can easily load files from it)

Every copy of SmileBASIC has the exact same files in `SYS`, and SB would not work without them.

The "clear everything" command, `ACLS`, loads the default sprite sheets and font from `SYS`, and they are also loaded automatically whenever a program is run from the main menu. The `FONTDEF` (reset font) command also loads from `SYS`

My question: *"Is it ok to load files from `SYS` without them counting towards the program size?"*

Comment: I'm not familiar with the environment, but how would this compare/contrast to built-in libraries in e.g., Python or Mathematica?

Answer (score 3):

There are no files in SYS that contain library functions, only samples, default assets, and a table of kanji characters. I personally don't consider the fact that some builtins load from SYS as loading an external file, and I can't imagine the default assets to be of much use to any sort of challenge. If we make it a "rule" that every program assumes some default environment, this isn't really an issue.

Comment: It's already a rule. We define a programming language by its implementation. Since this folder is part of the implementation, it can be accessed without penalty, assuming there's no `import` required.